# Send Distinguished CA List as part of TLS Handshake Server Hello

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-security

We have requirement in  our project that our service (WCF REST) will be consuming by different devices. Each device is having  unique client certificates which is generating from a common root certificate for all the devices using  an administration application.  Upon TLS negotiation, the server needs to send the client certificate request and  **the Distinguished CA list** . The client needs to fetch the client certificate based on the Distinguished CA list receiving with the ServerHello( TLS Handshake message ) .
I was able to do client certificate request. What should I need to do on WCF to include distinguished CA list ?.The WCF configuration i'm using is following.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFClientCertificateValidation.TestContract" behaviorConfiguration="clientcert">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFClientCertificateValidation.ITestContract"  behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp></webHttp>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientcert">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication customCertificateValidatorType="WCFClientCertificateValidation.DeviceCertificateValidator, WCFClientCertificateValidation" certificateValidationMode="Custom" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" >
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: For information about "Working with Certificates in WCF", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/working-with-certificates